# Can't get action result to run if statement and go to logged in section

Tags: asp.net-mvc

For some reason, The users in db.users.Where()is not working like the rest of the users in the code. Need some assistance to make it get to the logged in stage.

```
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(User users)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using(DataContext db = new DataContext())
                {
                    var obj = db.users.Where(u => u.Username.Equals(users.Username) && u.Password.Equals(users.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        Session["UserID"] = obj.UserID.ToString();
                        Session["Username"] = obj.Username.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("LoggedIn");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View(users);
        }

        public ActionResult LoggedIn()
        {
            if (Session["UserID"] != null)
            {
                return View();
            }
            else
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "not working" Also, I don't see a loop.

Comment: For some reason, when hovered, the users in db.users.Where() doesn't light up like the rest of them in my code. As for the loop, That was I think the wrong choice of words. The if statement is what I meant.

Comment: C# is case sensitive. What does your context have for "users" - normally I'd expect that as camel case like db.Users

Comment: Also, your user name might be case sensitive using Equals like this, or the password wouldn't be, which would be not the usual way to be. Depends on your db config etc. You're using Equals for both so I can't decide which you meant. One way or the other, it's not right  =)

Comment: All of it is in lower case other than the method in my context.